# How to set the ticker speed of radio button in code name one?

Tags: codenameone

Ok, the title is pretty direct ..how do i do it?

I saw something in DefaultLookAndFeel class...

so I tried DefaultLookAndFeel abc = new DefaultLookandFeel(UImanager.getinstance());

abc.settickerspeed(1000);

But it did not work. the ticker speed of radio button din change.

what should be done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
DefaultLookAndFeel d = ((DefaultLookAndFeel)UIManager.getInstamce().getLookAndFeel());
d.settickerspeed(1000);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work as expected. 

I tried ->1) d.settickerspeed(50);// gives default speed

2)d.settickerspeed(100);//slows down the ticker

3)d.setTickerSpeed(500);//slows down the ticker terribly

So to speed up the ticker , I tried:

1)d.setTickerSpeed(25);//gives default speed ..no visible improvement.

2)d.setTickerSpeed(10);// same as above

I tried all this on the inbuilt codename one editor.

How do i INCREASE the speed of the ticker?

Comment: Ticker speed indicates the delay, beyond a certain threshold you will reach the speed of the EDT "tick" which you can't surpass other than by skipping pixels. You can workaround this for an individual label but it will be harder to do this globally. You can file an issue about this and we can add something to workaround this.